# How to load data in Drop-down in Form in Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to load the information from the dataset to the drop-down in the form. I have created an object type using Ontology Manager. Next, I created the form and copied the `RID` of the dataset to the place where `RID` was asked for a drop-down. I saved the form. Next step I Shared the form with somebody else whose role was as a viewer. The viewer opens the form and the drop-down shows Loading Failed, Try again.

First I indexed my dataset. Then I copied the RID and pasted it from settings where `RID` was asked. Finally, I saved the form.
Still the drop-down showed Loading Failed, Try again

Answer (score 0):

The person you're sharing the form with has to have access to the data in the dropdown. If they don't have access to the backing object type they won't be able to see that data in the form.

Comment: If I share the backing object,they will be able to see.But If the person is a viewer then the backing object contents are not visible. If the data in backing object is not visible.What should be done?

Comment: Is the backing object in the same project? There is probably a different project you need to give the user access to.

Comment: The backing object is the same prooject.